# Why does it say "objects of unequal length"?

Tags: matrix

This is my code:

```
omega[t_, t0_, T_] = Exp[(-(t - t0)^2)/T^2];
omegap[t_, t0p_, Tp_] = Exp[-((t - t0p)^2)/Tp^2];
Δeff[t_, t0p_, Tp_] = ((omega[t, t0, T])^2 - (omegap[t, t0p, Tp])^2)/(2 Δ);
Ωeff[t_, t0p_, Tp_] = (omegap[t, t0p, Tp]*omega[t, t0, T])/(Δ);
ReducedHam = ({ {Δeff[t, t0p, Tp], Ωeff[t, t0p, Tp]*xp[Sqrt[-1]*φ]},
    {Ωeff[t, t0p, Tp]*Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*φ], -Δeff[t, t0p, Tp]} });
Print[MatrixForm[ReducedHam]]
θ[t_, t0p_, Tp_] = ArcTan[omegap[t, t0p, Tp]/omega[t, t0, T]];
λ1 = ({
    {Cos[θ]},
    {-Sin[θ]*Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*φ]}
   });
λ2 = ({
    {Sin[θ]*Exp[Sqrt[-1]*φ]},
    {Cos[θ]}
   });
Print[MatrixForm[λ1]]
Print[MatrixForm[λ2]]
Mat1 = (D[λ1, θ]).(Transpose[λ1]);
Print[Mat1]
V1 = Transpose[λ1].D[λ1, θ];
V2 = λ1.Transpose[λ1];
Print[MatrixForm[V2]]
Mat2 = {V1}.{V2};
Print[Mat2]
Print[MatrixForm[Simplify[Mat2]]]
Mat1 - Mat2
```

But when I try to combine matrices in the last line, it says they are incompatible even though when i print them, they each have four elements. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Because of dimensions that do not match:

```
Mat1 // Dimensions
Mat2 // Dimensions
```

> {2, 2}
>
> {1, 1, 2, 2}

Maybe you are more familiar with *Matlab*? Because *Matlab* natively knows only matrices, the standard construction operators always return matrices.

Maybe

```
ArrayFlatten[Mat2]
```

is the matrix that you expected to obtain. Anyways, if I where you, I would check whether `Mat2 = {V1}.{V2};` does what you want. It looks fishy to me.

Comment: Yeah, this is not doing what I want it to. I am trying to perform scalar multiplication on Matrix V2 with constant V1. I changed this to: Mat2 = V1 {V2} but this still does not give me a two by two matrix. When I create an arbitrary matrix (identity) named MatA and do x{MatA} (after defining x), it properly performs scalar mult., so I am not sure why it isn't working here.

Comment: this gives me a mat of 2 dimensions

Comment: Ah. Then try `V1[[1, 1]]  V2`.

Comment: it works !!! thanks ! can you please explain to me what this does ?

Comment: `V1` is a $1 \times 1$-matrix, not a scalar. So I read off the first entry in its first row -- _that_ is is a scalar.

Comment: thank you for the help !

Comment: You're welcome.